# Encryped Core file in website

Tags: web-services, core-file

I have a file called Core that is about 10 Mb. It is in the same directory that all the other main files of my website are in, such as Index.php. When I open it up, it looks encrypted. Can anyone tell me what the purpose of this file is?

My main concern is if the developer I worked with created this file for malicious purposes if he decides to use it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite probably this is what's called a [core dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) file. There is nothing malicious about it. It is used for debugging, and is safe to delete.

Of course, I have no way to know for certain without any additional information, but I'd bet it's a core dump file.

Comment: If you do decide that you want to delete it, you might want to rename it first and make sure things don't break - so that if things do break you can rename it back.

Comment: I want to thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. What additional info can I give you, short of FTP access, to be certain?

Comment: You could try to open the file in a core dump analyzer. It will be difficult to make any sense of it though. It is a copy of the memory state of a certain running program - usually at the moment that program terminated unexpectedly. It is absolutely meaningless unless you have some reference of just what the program might have been doing at the time the file was generated. In other words, you need to know how the file was created in order to make sense of it. For example, if you're in a GNU environment, and you know the core file came from apache, you might do `gdb httpd -c core` to read it.

Comment: So should I run it in a core dump analyzer? Any suggestions?

Comment: My main concern is if the developer put a backdoor into the files or can cause trigger something malicious or access user info or the code is not all there and some of it is relying on his server. Is there a way to check against any of these possibilities?

Comment: What should I look out for specifically for anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Core files are created when a unix executable crashes - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

It should be safe to delete it.